# Manipulating a data frame with contents from a different data frame similar to a SQL join

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a data frame with the contents:

```
Trial Person Time
1     John   1.2
2     John   1.3
3     John   1.1
1     Bill   2.3
2     Bill   2.5
3     Bill   2.7
```

and another data frame with the contents:

```
Person Offset
John   0.5
Bill   1.0
```

and I want to modify the original frame based on the appropriate value from the second. I could do this easily in any other language or in SQL, and I'm sure I could manage using for loops and what, but with everything else I see in R, I'm guessing it has special syntax to do this as a one-liner. So, if so, how? And if not, could you show how it could be done using loops. I haven't actually got around to learning looping in R yet since it has amazing things to simply extract and manipulate whatever values.

For reference, the output would:

```
Trial Person Time
1     John   0.7
2     John   0.8
3     John   0.6
1     Bill   1.3
2     Bill   1.5
3     Bill   1.7
```

Comment: you could have used a more specific title..

Comment: @dalloliogm Feel free to throw a recommendation....I got the answer I needed within ten minutes

Comment: yes but because the title was so general that people looked at it just to understand better what was it. So you have taken away the attention from other questions which maybe were better written, and that's unfair. A good title should be so that one can have an idea of what you are going to ask just by reading it. Anyway, peace, you haven't done anything too terrible, it's ok.

Comment: I'll change the title if you have a better way of describing it ... I just didn't know how I could describe my problem in a way that explained it perfectly.

Comment: Take a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right to figure out how to use merge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many possibilities. Here is a simple one using `merge()` and a simple column-wise subtraction in the enlarged `data.frame`:

```
R> DF1 <- data.frame(trial=rep(1:3,2), \
                     Person=rep(c("John","Bill"), each=3), \
                     Time=c(1.2,1.3,1.1,2.3,2.5,2.7))
R> DF2 <- data.frame(Person=c("John","Bill"), Offset=c(0.5,1.0))
R> DF <- merge(DF1, DF2)
R> DF
  Person trial Time Offset
1   Bill     1  2.3    1.0
2   Bill     2  2.5    1.0
3   Bill     3  2.7    1.0
4   John     1  1.2    0.5
5   John     2  1.3    0.5
6   John     3  1.1    0.5
R> DF$NewTime <- DF$Time - DF$Offset
R> DF
  Person trial Time Offset NewTime
1   Bill     1  2.3    1.0     1.3
2   Bill     2  2.5    1.0     1.5
3   Bill     3  2.7    1.0     1.7
4   John     1  1.2    0.5     0.7
5   John     2  1.3    0.5     0.8
6   John     3  1.1    0.5     0.6
R>
```

Comment: Ha! I just figured out a one-liner using a for loop, but this is even more beautiful. I didn't realize you could merge two frames, and it'll figure out where they go based on the column names.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
transform(merge(d1,d2), Time=Time - Offset, Offset=NULL)
```